# Unable to push data into JSON file AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have just started learning Angular js. I find difficulty in adding the data to an existing JSON file.

This is my JSON file

```
{"response":[ {
"Cust_Fname":"Jack",
"Cust_Lname":"Nicolson",
"Cust_Dob":"24/09/1992",
"Cust_Mob":"0987654321",
"Cust_Email":"abc@xyz.com"
},
{
"Cust_Fname":"tom",
"Cust_Lname":"cruise",
"Cust_Dob":"19/01/1990",
"Cust_Mob":"1234567890",
"Cust_Email":"sss@gmail.com",
}
]
}
```

This is my AngularJS code to push data

```
$scope.saveContact = function(contact){
$http.post('/data/Cust_Dtls.json',contact).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log(data)});
            }
```

This is my HTML file

```
<ion-content  class="item-noborder base-bg" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-50 pane-top-padding-20" style="padding-left:10px"><a class="button button-icon button-positive ion-arrow-left-c" href="#/tab/contacts">&nbsp;Back to Contacts</a></div>
            <div class="col-50 pane-top-padding-20 text-right"><a class="button button-icon button-positive ion-checkmark text-right" href="#/tab/contacts" ng-click="saveContact(contact)">&nbsp;Save</a></div>
        </div>



    <div  id="contact-div">

        <label class="item">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="contact.Cust_Fname">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="contact.Cust_Lname">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="contact.Cust_Email">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
            <span class="input-label">Phone</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="contact.Cust_Mob">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
            <span class="input-label">Date Of Birth</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="DOB" ng-model="contact.Cust_Dob">
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I am able to read the data using `$http.get` but i am unable to push data and i don't have any errors popping up. so i am unable to figure on what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the post verb of http instead of push

The format is taken from angular site:

```
// Simple POST request example (passing data) :
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

So taking your code you need to push contact like this:

```
$http.post('/data/Cust_Dtls',{contact:contact}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data)});
}
```

You need to post to a url instead of a json flat file.

Comment: @Venkatesh: updated the answer to have the contact sent to server

Comment: @Venkatesh: have you created the contact object?

Comment: yup I have created it.

Comment: you have the handle the post using a rest api url and not to a json. editing the answer...

Comment: oh yeah. just remembered it. thanks. So. then how do it insert it to an json file.? but then '$http.get' worked

Comment: @Venkatesh: a get will work as it is a flat file (a json file) and push it to the client side as a json object. However in post your server needs to read through the json file and then write on it. If this has helped please accept this as an answer.

Comment: i have my file locally in application storage. In that ase how do i write it to the file?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing same mistake I was doing. you trying to post data into local file using $http service.You cannot do this. $http service is for server-client communication. Use either localstorage or sqlite like services.

Hope this helps